# Is searching down for the entire StackExchange network?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I guess the title says it all.

For both StackOverflow and Meta here, whenever I search for something, I get taken to the "Oops! Something bad happened!" error page, regardless of what I search for.

From the HTML comment:

> Actual error: Invalid column name `Url`.

Comment: It's happening for me for certain tag searches on Math.SE, like [complex-analysis], but not for others.  Ah, my mistake; it's now happening on all searches.

Comment: with a username like that I'd say **you** are the prime suspect ;)

Comment: @Lix - touché! I swear I wasn't searching for `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE SearchResults; --` O:-)

Comment: The cat is working on it.

Comment: Seems to be working now...

Comment: That cat is *fast*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is fixed.

Honestly, I can't find what triggered it.

Let's just blame [Hurricane Sandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Sandy).